# Backbone.js set View attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm kind of new to Backbone and I'm having trouble understanding how to set the attributes of a View. I'm using a view without a model.

This is the View:

```
var OperationErrorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    attributes: {},
    render: function(){
        var html = "<h3>" + this.attributes.get("error") +"</h3>";
        $(this.el).html(html);
    }
})
```

Then later on:

```
if (errors.length > 0){
    errors.forEach(function(error){
        // var errorView = new OperationErrorView({attributes: {"error": error} });          Doesn't work
        var errorView = new OperationErrorView();
        errorView.set({attributes: {"error": error}})
        errorView.render()
        $("#formAdd_errors").append(errorView.$el.html());
    });
}
```

Which is the correct approach to do this? Right now it doesn't work: When I try the method that is not commented out, it gives me the error `TypeError: errorView.set is not a function`, if I try it the first way, it just doesn't call the render() function.

**UPDATE:**

```
var OperationErrorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    attributes: {},
    initialize: function(attributes){
        this.attributes = attributes;
    },
    render: function(){
        var html = "<h3>" + this.attributes.get("error") +"</h3>";
        console.log("html");
        $(this.el).html(html);
    }
})

if (errors.length > 0){
        errors.forEach(function(error){
            console.log(error);
            var errorView = new OperationErrorView({"error": error});
            errorView.render()
            $("#formAdd_errors").append(errorView.$el.html());
        });
    }
```

I tried including this.render() in the initialize function. Doesn't work. Doesn't even call the render function. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

- `set` is not a function of a Backbone View.  [Check the API](http://backbonejs.org/#View)
- In your commented code, calling `new OperationErrorView(...)` does not automatically evoke the `render` function.  You have to do this manually.
- The `attributes` property of the View does not have a `get` method.  Again, [Check the API](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes)

So, what should you do?

Research different ways to [initialize a View with properties](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).  Then figure out how to get those properties on the HTML that your View controls.

Here's a bit to get you started

```
var OperationErrorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'h3',

    initialize: function(attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        // attach attributes to this.$el, or this.el, here

        // insert the element into the DOM
        $('#formAdd_errors').append(this.$el);
    }
});

// later in your code
if ( errors.length > 0 ) {
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
        new OperationErrorView({ error: error });
    });
}
```

Comment: I know calling new View doesn't call render() automatically, that is why I call render() the next line. Anyway, thanks for you suggestion and links. However, it doesn't work, it doesn't call the render function I don't know why. Any ideas? Included an update with the new code.

Comment: I hadn't tested the code; was more of a guideline than anything else. I'm taking a deeper look at it now.

Comment: thanks chazsolo I found the error: `var html = "<h3>" + this.attributes.get("error") +"</h3>"` should be `var html = "<h3>" + this.attributes.error +"</h3>";` and it works.

Comment: Ahh I missed that!  I was busy workin on a jsfiddle to provide you with a working copy but it seems you found a way.  Glad I could help!

Comment: And a fourth thing: the `attributes` in the view definition are attached to the prototype so they'll be shared by all instances. The assignment in `initialize` stops the sharing but `attributes: {}` is still a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to chazsolo for the answer, all the info is there. So, I'll write the code that worked just in case someone finds it useful someday:

```
var OperationErrorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes){
        this.attributes = attributes;
    },
    render: function(){
        var html = "<h3>" + this.attributes.error +"</h3>";
        $(this.el).html(html);
    }
});

if (errors.length > 0){
    errors.forEach(function(error){
        var errorView = new OperationErrorView({'error':error});
        errorView.render()
        $("#formAdd_errors").append(errorView.$el.html());
    });
}
```